# function doesn't return variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this really easy and stupid question but I'm already stuck on 2 two days. 
I have to receive data from server or whatever and I wrote easy function, so 
this guy

```
$scope.myTar = function() {
    return 5;
};

$scope.identity = angular.identity;

$scope.range = function(min, max, step){
    step = Math.floor((max+5)/3);
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i < max+5; i += step)
        input.push(i);
    input.push($scope.myTar());
    return input;
};
```

and this guy

```
<div ng-repeat="n in range(0, gauge.gaugeData.target) |orderBy:identity">
    <div ng-class="{ 'numberGaugeBar-goal': n == myTar() }"></div>
    <div class="numberGaugeNumbers-hashHolder"></div>
    <div class="numberGaugeNumbers-numberHolder"> {{n}} </div>
</div>
```

return for me digit 5 and pushing it into my range

if I use this guy

```
$scope.myTar = function(target) {
    $log.debug('['+target+']')
};
```

it returns me on console all my necessary values
but if I use this guy

```
$scope.myTar = function(target) {
    return target;
};
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="n in range(0, gauge.gaugeData.target)|orderBy:identity">
    <div ng-class="{ 'numberGaugeBar-goal': n == myTar(gauge.gaugeData.target) }"></div>
    <div class="numberGaugeNumbers-hashHolder"></div>
    <div class="numberGaugeNumbers-numberHolder"> {{n}} </div>
</div>
```

it returns me in console target is undefined, what's wrong?

the gaugeData is coming from other function LoadGaugesData
I tried to input this part of code to myTar function but it still shows me same thing. Also as you can see my range is using gaugeData.target and it works fine...
this is part of it

```
for (var idx in $scope.sectionDescriptives.scoreSections) {
   section = $scope.sectionDescriptives.scoreSections[idx];
      for (var gaugeIdx in section.gauges) {
         var gauge = section.gauges[gaugeIdx];
         var gaugeData = $scope.getGaugeData(gauge.id);
         gauge.gaugeData = gaugeData;
         gauge.target = gaugeData.target;
         section.gauges[gaugeIdx].gaugeData = $scope.getGaugeData(gauge.id);
}}
```

Comment: Is the guage object attached to the scope at all?

Comment: yes, the guage object is attached to the scope at all

Comment: Could you give an example of what the object looks like?

Comment: then your `gaugeData` does not have a `target` field. Put a breakpoint in myTar and debug it. Also look at your scope's object tree in the debugger to see if gauge is really attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for stupid question, stupid answer

I inserted max in my push function inside range
like this

```
$scope.range = function(min, max, step){
    step = Math.floor((max+5)/3);
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i < max+5; i += step)
        input.push(i);
    input.push(**max**);
    return input;
};
```

thanks, for advice to check every step in debugger